# Azure B2C Returns Error Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid

Tags: .net, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have set up an application and api on Azure B2C. I have tried different variations but end up with the error Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid when I call an endpoint using Postman."

My set up on Azure is
[Azure App Registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q2ND.png)
My start up in .Net Core is :
s

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
                {
                    opt.Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:ResourceId"];
                    opt.Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}";
                    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = "https://https://CareHomeBookingTest.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/default"
                    };
                });
```

I am trying to call this endpoint which is protected by the Authorize attribute

```
[Authorize]        
 [Route("Secure")]
 [HttpGet("Residents")]
 [Produces("application/json")]

public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllResidents()
 {
     return Ok(await _mediator.Send(new ResidentGetAllQuery()));
 }
```

On Postman I can call and get the token :

[Postman values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZsfV.png)

The returned jwt token is

```
{
  "iss": "https://carehomebookingtest.b2clogin.com/d452b############-e150f022535e/v2.0/",
  "exp": 1633036666,
  "nbf": 1633022266,
  "aud": "e72a######################",
  "sub": "7ac#######################",
  "given_name": "john",
  "family_name": "smith",
  "tfp": "B2C_1_SignUpIn",
  "scp": "admin",
  "azp": "e72##################",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iat": 1633022266
}
```

But when I call the endpoint mentioned above I get the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q2ND.png)

Comment: Your Postman link is broken.

Comment: You’re protecting your API with AAD, but your token is from AAD B2C, hence it’ll never work. B2C api sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-web-app-with-api?tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT I have added the start up values as per the sample you provided and now I get the error "IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'."

Comment: New Values in the appsettings.json file are : "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "010e#########################",
    "Domain": "CareHomeBookingTest.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi_reset_v2",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpIn"
    //"CallbackPath": "/signin/B2C_1_sign_up_in"  // defaults to /signin-oidc
  }

Comment: Configure Services values are below. Not sure if I need to add the NameClaimType.  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
                    {
                        Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);

                        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "test";
                    },
            options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });

Comment: Instance is not correct. Doc is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application?tabs=visual-studio#step-6-add-the-app-settings

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT I have made the change and its all working now. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you    [Jas Suri - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8357357/jas-suri-msft) posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

So after changing the instance name in your `appsettings.json` as below ,based on this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application?tabs=visual-studio#step-6-add-the-app-settings)   hopefully resolved your issue .

```
"AzureAdB2C": { "Instance": "https://<your-tenant-name>.b2clogin.com", 
"ClientId": "<web-app-application-id>", 
"Domain": "<your-b2c-domain>", 
"SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/<your-sign-up-in-policy>", 
"SignUpSignInPolicyId": "<your-sign-up-in-policy>" }
```

For more information please refer this Microsoft documentation:  [Configure authentication in a sample web app that calls a web API by using Azure AD B2C.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-web-app-with-api?tabs=visual-studio)